# Webapp to create screenshots of Android app with various devices

Tags: android, screenshot, play-store

**CONTEXT:** The Android marketplaces all require screenshots in various sizes. For instance, Play Store wants phone, 7-inch tablet, 10-inch tablet, TV. It is a pain to create emulators for all sizes.

**QUESTION:** Is there a webapp (hosted not by me) that gives me screenshots of my app in various sizes?

Requirements:

- Free
- Pre-set with common sizes or popular devices
- Including Android TV
- Ideally allows me to navigate in the app to select what I want to take a screenshot of
- Ideally supports [APK expansion files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)
- Ideally makes it easy to download PNG screenshots without having to screenshot the web page itself